# Get the modified date of two files and compare to do a task?

Tags: batch-file

I've got two files and I need to get the modified date, I've found the solution this way:

```
for %%a in (file1.txt) do set Fechh1=%%~ta
for %%a in (file2.txt) do set Fecha2=%%~ta
```

Then I want to compare the two dates and if the file2 date is newer than the file1 make a task (copy certain files).

But it's making the comparison as strings not as dates.

Comment: This site is not a site where you post a script which does not attempt the task you want it to do, and ask for others to make it do that. Here we expect that you post code written to do the task, but which fails to do so. Please search this site for examples of comparing timestamps, try to implement what you've learned, then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55352784/edit) to include a [mcve] of the code complete with a full explanation of how it fails to achieve what was intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work for you:

```bat
if exist "file1.txt" if exist "file2.txt" (
    for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%A IN ('dir /B /A-D /OD "file1.txt" "file2.txt"') do (
        if "%%A" == "file2.txt" (copy certain files) else (echo Unfortunately, file1.txt is newer)
    )
)
```

First, a check is performed in order to see if files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.

Then, check if the newest file is `file2.txt` via a `dir` command parsed in a `for /F` loop.

For more info about the commands used, please type the following commands in cmd:

- `if /?`
- `for /?`
- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`